# .NET complex music API

Tags: c#, api

I'm searching for some sound API which can play mp3 and flac files and streamed online radio too.

Currently i'm using libZPlay but it didn't play a streamed mp3.

I'm looked on a NAudio but i don't understand how to play stream via this library, it's little bit complicated API.

I'm using C#.

Thanks for answers.

Comment: There are a lot of VLC wrappers for .NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used [BASS Audio](http://www.un4seen.com/) (click BASS on the left) with success and can stream most files. I believe there is a plugin for BASS that will allow it to play FLAC content as well. It's free for non-commercial use and has a .Net API as well.

Comment: with all that plugins it's amazing API...Many thanks :)